# as3 dynamic variable within a loop

Tags: actionscript-3, class, loops, dynamic, variables

I need to have the `screenPage` var accessible for later calls. I am dynamically creating several pages. The issue is when I call `screenPage.startDrag();` then it only drags the last page. How can I add a var in the name or make all the screenPages accessible through code?

Here is code in short:

```
var screenPage:MovieClip;

for(var p = 1; daTotalPages >= p; p++)
{
    screenPage = new theFlagScreen();
}
```

**Can I make `screenPage` a dynamic var and add like a 1 at the end and then a 2 and so forth with the loop?**

Comment: I don't know what else to change to make this better. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an array ?

```
var pages:Array = new Array;

for(var p = 1; daTotalPages >= p; p++)
{
   var screenPage:MovieClip = new theFlagScreen();
   pages.push(screenPage)
}
```

Now you have an array containing all of your instances.

```
var myPage:MovieClip = pages[5] as MovieClip;
myPage.startDrag();
```

Also, the code you have above is creating an instance each time through, but since you then go ahead and create a new one each iteration and assign it to the same variable without storing it or adding it to the display list.... once you create a new one, the last one is marked for garbage collection.

The result is only the LAST instance you created still exists as it's the only one that has a variable that references it.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. That did it. Amazing! I love stackoverflow people! So fast, so giving!

Comment: That would be helpful. Thanks. I don't think you get my comments if the question is answered. I guess. I love this site but I wish they would make it a little more free. I am trying my best.

Answer (score 1):

`screenPage` is a reference to just ONE thing. In your loop you keep overwriting it as you go and so you end up with it pointing to the very last instance of `theFlagScreen`... all the others are now lost.

You should follow prototypical's advice and store these instances in an array, that way you don't lose them.